# Exclude weekends in calculating difference of two dates in access

Tags: database, date, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2016

I am working on an access database for a project and need some help which I cannot solve. I have two date columns Actual Date and Delivery Date which are subtracted from to give a difference eg. Actual date can be 12/05/2017 and Delivery Date can be 16/05/17 subtracted the answer is 4, now my problem is I need to exclude weekends from the calculation, if the actual date is a Thursday and the Delivery Date is a Tuesday the difference should be 4 days and not 6 because the weekends shouldn't count. I need to implement this in Microsoft Access and have the difference show on a report.

If anyone can assist.

Comment: This topic has been addressed many times. Example solutions may be in this forum, certainly in others. Google: Access VBA calculate working days. Here is one https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd327646(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is datediff interval "weekday" returning interval based on weeks and not days minus weekends?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43662164/why-is-datediff-interval-weekday-returning-interval-based-on-weeks-and-not-day)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative VBA function to calculate workdays between two dates.  By "alternative", I agree with June7 that this has been addressed elsewhere including many code samples. However, in my testing the following code is over 4 times faster than the function in [the link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd327646(v=office.12).aspx).  This speed difference is significant when called from queries of large datasets.  Also, my code produces consistent results for reverse-order date parameters and when the start or end dates are on weekends.  Other code, including those linked to in the comments, do not exhibit ALL of the following:

- Unique value for case when there are NO weekdays (same weekend) in specified range.
- Handles reverse date order by returning negative number of days when first date comes before second.
- Consistency with reverse date orders by always returning the negative of the swapped date order.
- Consistency with date range ending or starting within a weekend.  Other functions sometimes count +1 going into or coming out of the weekend, yet there is no such extra +1 when going over the entire weekend.  Also, with other functions there may be inconsistencies between starting vs ending in the weekend.

**Return values of WorkdayDiff function:**

- For d1 <= d2, it returns the total number of weekdays in the given range, inclusive.
- For d1 > d2, returns a negative number. For **only positive** values, the last line of code can be changed to `WorkdayDiff = (diff + 1)` or the call to the function can be wrapped with `Abs()`.

  - WorkdayDiff(d1, d2) == - WorkdayDiff(d2, d1)
- The function returns 0 if both dates fall on the same weekend.

To facilitate both negative numbers and the special 0 return value without throwing errors for out-of-bound dates, the function must behave like DateDiff(...) ±1 for typical workdays. E.g. `WorkdayDiff(Date, Date)` returns 1 instead of 0 as `DateDiff("d", Date, Date)` does.

(Incidentally, the numbers in the question text are not consistent, so it's not clear which behavior is expected/desired. The point is that you may need to check for 0 and/or subtract 1 from the answer to get your desired result.)

```
Public Function WorkdayDiff(ByVal d1 As Date, ByVal d2 As Date) As Long
  Dim diff As Long, sign As Long
  Dim wd1 As Integer, wd2 As Integer

  diff = DateDiff("d", d1, d2)
  If diff < 0 Then
    '* Effectively swap d1 and d2; reverse sign
    diff = -diff
    sign = -1
    wd1 = Weekday(d2)
  Else
    sign = 1
    wd1 = Weekday(d1)
  End If
  wd2 = (wd1 + diff - 1) Mod 7 + 1

  If (wd1 = 1 And diff = 0) Or (wd1 = 7 And diff <= 1) Then
    WorkdayDiff = 0 '* Both dates are on same weekend
    Exit Function
  End If

  '* If starting or ending date fall on weekend, shift to closest weekday
  '* since the weekends should not contribute to the sum.
  '* This shift is critical for the last If condition and arithmetic.
  If wd1 = 1 Then
    wd1 = 2 '* Shift to Monday
    diff = diff - 1
  ElseIf wd1 = 7 Then
    wd1 = 2 '* Shift to Monday
    diff = diff - 2
  End If

  If wd2 = 1 Then
    diff = diff - 2 '* Shift to Friday
  ElseIf wd2 = 7 Then
    diff = diff - 1 '* Shift to Friday
  End If

  '* If difference goes beyond weekend boundary then...
  If diff >= 7 - wd1 Then
    '* Normalize span to start on Monday for modulus arithmetic
    '* then remove weekend days
    diff = diff - ((diff + (wd1 - 2)) \ 7) * 2
  End If

  WorkdayDiff = sign * (diff + 1)
End Function
```

To address holidays, a single, simple query to a holiday table can be performed.  My suggestion would be to have the table already flagged (with a boolean field) whether a holiday is on a weekend or not, or just exclude weekend holidays altogether to improve speed. Otherwise, the query below will select on weekday-only holidays for you.  This assume a single table [Holidays] with a single field [holiday] where all values are for non-working days.

```
Public Function WorkdayDiff2(ByVal d1 As Date, ByVal d2 As Date) As Long
  Dim diff As Long, sign As Long
  Dim wd1 As Integer, wd2 As Integer
  Dim holidays As Long
  Dim SQLRange As String

  diff = DateDiff("d", d1, d2)
  If diff < 0 Then
    '* Effectively swap d1 and d2; reverse sign
    diff = -diff
    sign = -1
    wd1 = Weekday(d2)
    SQLRange = "([holiday] >= #" & d2 & "# AND [holiday] <= #" & d1 & "#)"
  Else
    sign = 1
    wd1 = Weekday(d1)
    SQLRange = "([holiday] >= #" & d1 & "# AND [holiday] <= #" & d2 & "#)"
  End If
  wd2 = (wd1 + diff - 1) Mod 7 + 1

  If (wd1 = 1 And diff = 0) Or (wd1 = 7 And diff <= 1) Then
    WorkdayDiff2 = 0 '* Both dates are on same weekend
    Exit Function
  End If

  '* If starting or ending date fall on weekend, shift to closest weekday
  '* since the weekends should not contribute to the sum.
  '* This shift is critical for the last If condition and arithmetic.
  If wd1 = 1 Then
    wd1 = 2 '* Shift to Monday
    diff = diff - 1
  ElseIf wd1 = 7 Then
    wd1 = 2 '* Shift to Monday
    diff = diff - 2
  End If

  If wd2 = 1 Then
    diff = diff - 2 '* Shift to Friday
  ElseIf wd2 = 7 Then
    diff = diff - 1 '* Shift to Friday
  End If

  '* If difference goes beyond weekend boundary then...
  If diff >= 7 - wd1 Then
    '* Normalize span to start on Monday for modulus arithmetic
    '* then remove weekend days
    diff = diff - ((diff + (wd1 - 2)) \ 7) * 2
  End If

  '* For efficiency, it is recommended that this be set as a global or class-level
  '* variable and its value maintained between repetative calls as in a query.
  '* Otherwsie, it can be slow since retrieval of Currentdb is an expensive operation.
  Dim db As Database
  Set db = CurrentDb

  holidays = db.OpenRecordset( _
      "SELECT Count([holiday]) FROM [Holidays]" & _
      " WHERE Weekday([holiday]) Not In (1, 7) AND " & SQLRange, _
      dbOpenForwardOnly, dbReadOnly).Fields(0).Value

  WorkdayDiff2 = sign * (diff + 1 - holidays)
End Function
```